# How would you create a keyframe animation in javaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I want to create an animation that is responsive to the users display height. I created a variable that stores the height of the document in javaScript but I dont know how to create a keyframe animation in javaScript that will allow be to use that variable.

For example, if I wanted this keyframe animation to be created in javaScript, how would I do it.

```
@keyframes fadeIn {
    from{
        opacity:0%;
        
    }

    to{
        opacity:100%;
        
    }
    
}
```

Comment: You can pass a variable from JS to CSS Is that what you need to do? Or are you trying to write the whole keyframes definition from JS?

Comment: It's better to do it in CSS.

Answer (score 0):

You can go for any js animation library. I would recommend GSAP (GreenSock Animation Platform) or anime.js.

For example, in GSAP you can accomplish such things:

```
var element = document.querySelector('.myElement');

gsap.to(element, {
  duration: 2,
  keyframes: [
    { opacity: 0, scale: 0 },
    { opacity: 1, scale: 1.2 },
    { opacity: 1, scale: 1 }
  ],
  repeat: -1 // Repeat indefinitely
});
```

Also check out **anime.js** .They provide a variety of advance css animation properties.

Answer (score 0):

You also can resolve this problem from the other perspective.
You can use CSS Variable inside your keyframes like this

```
@keyframes maxHeightAnimated{
    from{
        max-height: 0;
    }
    to{
        max-height: var(--document-height)
    }
}
```

And then you can just set the value of the CSS variable dynamically at any point that you want via your JS:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
    let r = document.querySelector(':root')
    r.style.setProperty('--document-height',document.body.offsetHeight + 'px')
    $(window).on('resize', () => {
        let r = document.querySelector(':root')
        r.style.setProperty('--document-height',document.body.offsetHeight + 'px')
    });
}
```

In the example, I am setting this value on document loaded and window resize events. What guarantees me that --document-height always contains actual height